# Why is encryption considered safer?

Tags: encryption, credentials, password-encryption, storing-information

This has puzzled me for a while now. I don't have a broad understanding on encryption, but I understand the principle.
For the sake of an example, let's assume I have a program whose sole purpose is to post a random user's input to my private facebook profile. Now to do this, the program must have my login information to facebook (if this is not the case, assume another third-party application). This information, or credentials, must be stored somewhere, since the program's post method would be done without administration.

I know it is a bad policy to store the login credentials in the code as plain strings, as the compiled code can be decompiled and my credentials would be readable. The recommended solution is to store them in a separate file, encrypted.

As far as I understand, the encryption / decryption needs a key that also needs to be stored somewhere. Can't this key and the encryption algorithm be read from the decompiled code and used to decrypt the credentials?

Is the benefit of storing the credentials encrypted based on the extra step on decompile-decrypt, or have I drastically misunderstood something?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: There are strategies that make it non-trivial to gain access to a well stored key ([where to store a key for encryption](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/12332/where-to-store-a-key-for-encryption)).

Comment: @beatcracker Thanks, I'll try there also, but I'll leave this open here anyway, since I find this very closely related to my own programming.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways one could check supplied credentials when you have encrypted version:

1. Decrypt the encrypted version; this would obviously require storing the tools necessary to decryption, which is unsafe
2. Encrypt what you are trying to check, and see if it matches your encrypted version.  This does *not* require the ability to decrypt anything.

Comment: The step 2 is a common misunderstanding in my question. There is nothing to compare against. No-one gives credential input. The user just types "Hello world!", and the program posts this to the service, be it facebook or whatever. The credentials must be stored and opened so the program can use them without administration.

Comment: If it is a "common misunderstanding", it's quite obvious that is not the case.

Comment: Touché.. Maybe I should edit the previous comment instead.